# Faceting on Search multiple indexes feature from Algolia

Tags: javascript, algolia

I am running a query on more than one of my indexes (by using [this](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/multiple-queries/) and everything works fine. Now, I want to implement a faceted search using such functionality ([this](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/faceting/)) but I am not being able to do it since I don't instantiate an index per each query I want to run. I tried to find some information out there about this but I was not able to find a solution for my problem and I want to avoid instantiating multiple indexes. Ideas?

This is a piece of the code I am using to search with multiple queries:

```
query.push({
    indexName: 'My Index',
    query: 'My Query', //I would like to use here something like 'NOT customAttr:"my value"'
    params: {
        hitsPerPage: 5
    }
});
client.search(query, function searchDone(){});
```

Comment: For each query of your batch, you can add the facet parameters of your choice. Which API client are you using?

Comment: We are using the JS API (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.min.js). Could you, please, provide an example of adding the faceted parameters? Because I need to define them prior to being able to filter the query by those facets and that's what I am not being able to do.

Comment: Can you give us a code sample that you are using today? Thanks

Comment: Added to the question. Thank you.